# HTTP Request Image

Tags: image, http, request, response

Say I request an image from a website. It returns me an image, I can see it in a browser, but when I go and inspect this request in debugger I see 200 OK, but there's nothing in response body. How can it be? Im confused.

Comment: Please add details

Comment: Nothing special. Im trying this on this link - https://www.google.ru/images/nav_logo242.png. Go see for yourself.

Comment: Which debugger do you use?

Comment: google chrome. it says 24kbs or so are transfered. why it is not loaded in response preview. is it binary or what?

Comment: I believe it's chrome console issue with PNG images